# Web scraping document with multiple HTTP logins

Tags: php, authentication, web-scraping, html, file-get-contents

I am trying to scrape a page from a website using php's `file_get_contents`.

However, the website requires two consecutive HTTP logins (using [basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)) before displaying the page I wish to scrape.

1. Dialog box pops up asking for username and password
2. After filling that out, another one pops up asking for the same details
3. After successful authentication with both dialogs, the scrape-target page is loaded

Is there anyway to scrape the contents of that webpage with predefined usernames and passwords on a page that requires multiple HTTP logins?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can perform only one log in with one request. So to perform two, you have to send two requests.

Comment: Yup, but I would recommend you use cURL instead for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @HorseSMith I also prefer cURL, but `file_get_contents()` should do the job.